# Applescript errors when reading user input (password) that contains escape characters

Tags: applescript

Here in my department we use a samba shares server as storage space for employees. For the employees that use Apple machines, we are trying to use an AppleScript application that will obtain the users username and password, then using them to mount the drives. The problem arises when a user enters a password that contains escape characters; for example **abcdefg/**. Here is the dialog code that sets the variables for username and password:

```
set user_name_dialog to display dialog "Enter your User ID: " default answer "" buttons {"Next"} default button "Next"
set user_name to text returned of user_name_dialog
--this line prompts the user for their password and sets the returned result as the variable "user_password"
set user_password_dialog to display dialog "Enter your Password. " & return & return & "WARNING: If you are running Panther (MacOS 10.3), your input will be displayed in this box as clear text." default answer "" buttons {"Next"} default button "Next" with hidden answer
set user_password to text returned of user_password_dialog
```

And here is the shell script line that is ran for mounting a drive:

```
do shell script "mount -t smbfs //" & user_name & ":" & user_password & "@SOME IP ADDRESS/SOME FOLDER/ /SOME MOUNT POINT/" & user_name & "-SOME SHARE"
```

Now I know from a little research that it could be something as simple as an extra pair of quotes somewhere, I've even tried

```
quoted form of
```

with no luck whatsoever. The error message I get when entering a string with a escape character is as such:

```
error "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host" number 68
```

Any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated as my experience with AppleScript is very limited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mounting an SMB drive via AppleScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727128/mounting-an-smb-drive-via-applescript)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: the following is just a guess. I did not test any of it.

I don't believe it is an "escape characters" problem. The forward slash is not an escape character. The backward slash is. The problem is probably that the smbfs command interprets the forward slash as a divisor for path variables, and that's causing the error. So the question becomes... how can you avoid the conflict between the forward slash and the smbfs command?

I would try escaping the forward slash when you pass the command to the shell. Note that applescript also uses a backslash as an escape character so to pass an escape character to the shell you will have to escape the escape. So write a custom handler to pass your passwords through to perform that escape process for you.

So if this is your password, "abcdefg/" then try passing it as "abcdefg\\/" (note the double backslash). As mentioned you can write a custom handler to check your password for the "/" character, and if found then insert "\\" in front of it. But before writing that handler try the proposed solution manually to see if it solves your problem.

```
set pword to "/abc/defg/"
escapeSlash(pword)

on escapeSlash(x)
    if x contains "/" then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
        set textItems to text items of x
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\\/"
        set x to textItems as text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    end if
    return x
end escapeSlash
```

Comment: Yeah trying that didnt work I wouod post the error message but I'm mobile at the moment. How would you best implement the string handler? My knowledge of applescript really is quite abysmal.

Comment: I added a handler using AppleScript's text item delimiters to do the work. They control the separator when you coerce a string to a list with "text items" and back again with "as text". So we can manipulate them to derive our outcome.

Comment: After trying your handler, this is the error I receive ' error mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host number 68 '. I also received this when manually setting the slashes to \\/.